# Formula referencing from other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA and I'm having trouble debugging a certain code. What I want is a cell formula that has the formula link to another spreadsheet. However, I want to add cells from multiple workbooks. For example, if we had workbook1 and workbook 2. I want in cell F10 in final workbook to have formula reading '[workbook1]Sheet1'!!F10' + '[workbook2]Sheet1'!!F10'

I like to make the formula as flexible and have the following conditions

1. I like to have an open directory that lets me select excel files that I want as part of the formula
2. I can add as many external spreadsheets as possible
3. The final spreadsheet initially will have zeroes in them. I want to replace this with a formula link.

How i decided to code this is by first replacing the zero cell of the final workbook with cell F10 of first excel file selected from a directory. Once this step is done, any additional workbooks selected from directory will add on as an extra formula link to the cell. Below is a code I attempted but I can not figure why it doesn't work. Could anyone please let me know what is going wrong? Thanks.

```
Sub Sum_workbooks_Form()
    Dim FileNameXls, f
    Dim wb As Workbook, i As Integer

    FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

    If Not IsArray(FileNameXls) Then Exit Sub

    
    
    For Each f In FileNameXls
        
       
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
            
           
               If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, 6).Value = 0 Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, 6).Formula = "=[" & wb.Name & "]Sheet1!" & Cell(11, 6).Name
                Else
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, 6).Formula = "=[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]Sheet1!" & Cell(11, 6).Name & " + [" & wb.Name & "]Sheet1!" & Cell(11, 6).Name
                End If
          

            
            
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next f

   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, normally a reference to cell F10 of Sheet1 of Book2 is expressed like this in a formula:

```vb
=[Book2]Sheet1!$F$10
```

Is it possible for you to reference the Sheet NAME instead of the NUMBER?
If yes, the first of your assignments should look like this:

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(9).Cells(11, 6).Formula = "=[" & wb.Name & "]Sheet1!$F$10"
```

Where `Sheet1` is of course the name of your Sheets(9)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I want numbers is because I wanted to do a number loop for all the sheets. I can create a list loop for the sheets. I'm hoping to do a number loop for the cells but its too many for cells. I'm just building it basic first. I made edits in my code above to reflect your suggestion but the code still have issues running. Could you let me know how to fix. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you use something like  `& Cell(11, 6).Name`... the formula should return the value (not the name) of cell F10 (you wrote above), so you should use the exact syntax I wrote you above...

Comment: I mean, you cannot just use the syntax you want, say, VBA syntax in a formula.
Different would be if instead of writing a formula, you want your code to calculate the value and write it in the result cell. These are two totally different approaches.

Comment: I want to loop it across all cells. Once I can get a single case working. I can change it to something like & Cell(i, j).Name where i and j are all the rows I want to apply this to. If I write $F$10, then I can't use it for a loop. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Never Mind. I figured it out. & Cell(11, 6).Address is the right syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I can't give you a like cos my rep is too low.